# Linking SQL to AutoCAD 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, autocad

**So I have learned how to create a connection between AutoCAD and my SQL Server using the 'DBCONNECT MANAGER' tool within AutoCAD.**

My next goal is to try and change the value/text of an existing label I have created in AutoCAD through an SQL update.

I am fairly experienced in SQL but I am very new to AutoCAD and the whole SQL-AutoCAD integration process in general.

I am setting up this question to ask if someone could point me the right way to achieving this SQL update.

Ultimately I want to be able to change the value of the label that is inside my AutoCAD project save from SQL.

Any advice/help/links/tutorials on this type of stuff would be extremely helpful as I have found very little on the web about this.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: are you using programming or AutoCAD built-in features? (looks like the second)

Comment: AutoCAD built in features (DbConnect Manager) , but ultimately I would want to be able to change data within the AutoCAD project from my SQL query without the AutoCAD project even being open or active.

Comment: I don't believe the built-in feature will be that powerful (e.g. edit DWG not opened on screen).... you may need some programming here.

Comment: You would need to have a listener that would handle a message from your sql. To edit the drawing (AutoCAD project?) without it being opened in the AutoCAD editor you would need to get access to the drawing file through libraries designed to do that. (RealDWG from Autodesk and Teigha from Open Design Alliance are 2 options)